# Importing and using ELF modules in python on Debian and AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, dependencies, elf

I'm trying to run some Python code and its unit tests on Debian (my local machine and a CI server). The code already runs on an AWS Lambda, and uses ELFs manually built on an AWS EC2 linux instance (these are the dependencies, such as scipy, numpy, etc).

However when I try to run the unit tests on my local machine, I get the following error after the ELFs are loaded. Things seem to go wrong at import. I have ensured that I've removed my local libraries (scipy, numpy, etc...).

[image: error messages on running unit tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGAog.png)

```
_________________ ERROR collecting test/unit_tests/MalfunctioningSensorsLambda/test_malfunctioning_scores.py _________________
test/unit_tests/MalfunctioningSensorsLambda/test_malfunctioning_scores.py:4: in <module>
    import malfunctioning
src/MalfunctioningSensorsLambda/malfunctioning.py:29: in <module>
    from scipy.stats import norm, mstats #, wasserstein_distance
lib-python/scipy/stats/__init__.py:343: in <module>
    from .stats import *
lib-python/scipy/stats/stats.py:169: in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
lib-python/scipy/special/__init__.py:640: in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
__init__.pxd:155: in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy/special/_ufuncs.c:39918)
    ???
E   ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 88, got 96
```

I'm not very experienced with deploying on AWS, so I would like to know your thoughts on the following questions: What is the best practice for such a scenario? Should the modules built in the EC2 instance be usable on Debian? Or, should I build the modules for every platform that I use my code on instead?

Comment: paste error _as text_ please

Comment: thanks, have done as you suggested.